# How to access JSON elements return from AJAX query

Tags: jquery, json

I am using ajax to get data from a datasource.   The Developer tools show me the ajax GET operation is returning the correct data, but my attempts to access the data to display on the html page is not working.  Can you see why ?

I have copied my code from another application that works fine,  so I'd have thought it would work - but somewhere I've made an error but I can't see where.

Here's the JSON code returned from the AJAX Get call:

```
[{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"Client Sites (local)","LINKSCATEGORYID":8},
{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"CMS (Local)","LINKSCATEGORYID":41},
{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"Music Library and Playlists","LINKSCATEGORYID":24},
{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"Our Sites (Local)","LINKSCATEGORYID":7},
{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"Radio Prep","LINKSCATEGORYID":18},
{"LINKSCATEGORYNAME":"Stats Reports","LINKSCATEGORYID":17}]
```

And here's my attempt to make

```
$.getJSON("linksdaoproxy.cfc?method=getCategoriesForMajorCatID&returnformat=json",{"argsLinksMajorCategoryID":selectedID}, function(res,code) {
          var newoptions = "";
            for(var i=0; i<res.DATA.length; i++) {
                newoptions += "<option value=\"" + res.DATA[i] + "\">" + res.DATA[i] + "</option>";
            $("#LinksCategoryID").children().end().append(newoptions);
        });
```

The error in the console says:

```
EditLinkbean.cfm:200 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

and the line referenced is the one with the for(var ... function.

Comment: There is no `DATA` property in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your DATA in 
  `for(var i=0; i<res.DATA.length; i++)`

is null, thus nullpointer saying you cannot read .length of (DATA - undefined).

(Missleading! left for future information)
`and JSON objects start with {}, not with [].`

Try to return something like {RESULT:[yourarray]}

Comment: `JSON starts with {}, not with []` That is not true. It can start with either one of them, or in fact just a `"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this. It does not access the `DATA` property (as it does not exist on your return (It cant even exist, because it is an array).

```
$.getJSON("linksdaoproxy.cfc?method=getCategoriesForMajorCatID&returnformat=json",{"argsLinksMajorCategoryID":selectedID}, function(res,code) {
    var newoptions = "";
    for(var i=0; i<res.length; i++) {
        newoptions += "<option value=\"" + res[i].LINKSCATEGORYID + "\">" + res[i].LINKSCATEGORYNAME + "</option>";
    }
    $("#LinksCategoryID").children().end().append(newoptions);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several issues here:

- There is no `DATA` property in the JSON returned form the AJAX request, you can just access `res` directly.
- You need to retrieve the properties of the object in the loop, ie. `LINKSCATEGORYNAME` and `LINKSCATEGORYID` and concatenate them to the HTML string you create, not the object itself.
- Your `for` loop doesn't need a closing `)`
- The `append()` call needs to go outside the loop.

With all that said, try this:

```js
var res = [{
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "Client Sites (local)",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 8
}, {
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "CMS (Local)",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 41
}, {
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "Music Library and Playlists",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 24
}, {
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "Our Sites (Local)",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 7
}, {
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "Radio Prep",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 18
}, {
  "LINKSCATEGORYNAME": "Stats Reports",
  "LINKSCATEGORYID": 17
}]

//$.getJSON("linksdaoproxy.cfc?method=getCategoriesForMajorCatID&returnformat=json", { "argsLinksMajorCategoryID": selectedID }, function(res, code) {
  var newoptions = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    newoptions += '<option value="' + res[i].LINKSCATEGORYID + '">' + res[i].LINKSCATEGORYNAME + '</option>';
  }
  $("#LinksCategoryID").append(newoptions);
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="LinksCategoryID"></select>
```

Also note that you can use `map()` and template literals to make the logic in the callback a little more succinct. The latter is unsupported in IE, though.

```
var newoptions = res.map(function(obj) {
  return `<option value="${obj.LINKSCATEGORYID }">${obj.LINKSCATEGORYNAME}</option>`;
});
$("#LinksCategoryID").append(newoptions);
```

Comment: Thank you MauriceNino   that did the trick!!!!  I am very grateful.      I used code from another project that worked fine,   which is where the res.DATA   came from.     The DATA isnt needed here, ... is that because the other project was using a comma delimited list rather than an array?